# what kind of socket would tomcat's accept() method create

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat

Tomcat's method : [accept() declaration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jni/Socket.html#accept%28long%29)

It says

> **Returns**: A copy of the socket that is connected to the socket that made the connection request.

Let's say I assigned 8080 as tomcat's port,and of course a socket is bound to 8080 port and was set to listening STATE.

In the accept() method,does it return a copy of the very socket that's bound and listening 8080?

what's the new socket's address and port?still 8080?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Returns: A copy of the socket that is connected to the socket that made the connection request.

Poorly worded. It returns what the Berkeley Sockets `accept()` method returns: a new socket. The new socket's attributes are all inherited from the listening socket (at the Sockets API level: this does not apply in Java for example, which resets some things such as `SO_TIMEOUT`). That includes the listening port number.

> Let's say I assigned 8080 as tomcat's port,and of course a socket is bound to 8080 port and was set to listening STATE.
>
> In the accept() method,does it return a copy of the very socket that's bound and listening 8080?
>
> what's the new socket's address and port?still 8080?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks,`accept(long sock)` in tomcat is a native method :(

Comment: I had grasped that, answered accordingly.